# Freeze a Rigid Body right up until impact?

Tags: rigid-body-simulation

I want a simple animation, where an object is hurled towards another object.
I want the impacted object as an Active Rigid Body, but I want it to freeze where it is right up until the frame before the impacting object hits it. I did this by key framing the “Animate” box to turn off on the frame right before the impact. This works, but when I go to Copy this setting to other objects using Rigid Body>Copy from active, all of the other objects copy the basic info without the keyframe. **Why is this happening?**

[image]

Comment: because it says "rigid body> copy" it copies only the rigid body settings, not the animation. If you wanna copy animation data, select all objects, the object with the animation at last (with shift-select) and press ctrl-l -> link animation data

Comment: @Chris I think you can give that as an answer

Answer (score 1):

Because it says "rigid body> copy" it copies only the rigid body settings, not the animation. If you wanna copy animation data, select all objects, the object with the animation at last (with shift-select) and press ctrl-l -> link animation data